# Ajax loaded form replaces form action with Ajax url

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, forms

I am making a Wordpress website using WPForms to use different forms. These WPForms are loaded in a modal using an Ajax trigger on a button click. When I click a button, the ID of the button is used to determine the ID of the form, which is then used in the WPForms shortcode to output the correct form.

The problem however is that the form `action` is replaced with the Admin ajax url when submitting the form. This results in a blank page returning `0`.

I need below ajax url to use ajax in the first place. How can I prevent the form action being changed?

**HTML**

```
    <?php $cf_object = get_sub_field('kaartje_button_cf'); ?>
    <a data-value="<?php echo $cf_object->ID; ?>" class="modal_trigger cta <?php echo $a_class; ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#bestelModal">
        <?php
        echo $cta_svg;
        echo $button_text ?>
    </a>
```

**Ajax**

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'ajax_fetchCF' );
function ajax_fetchCF() { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery('.modal_trigger').click(function () {
            var element = jQuery(this).data('value');
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>',
                type: 'POST',
                beforeSend: function () {
                    jQuery('.ajax-loader').show();
                    jQuery('#datafetch').hide();
                },
                complete: function () {
                    jQuery('.ajax-loader').hide();
                    jQuery('#datafetch').fadeIn();
                },
                data: {
                    action: 'data_fetchCF',
                    keyword: element
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    jQuery('#datafetch').html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php }

add_action( 'wp_ajax_data_fetchCF', 'data_fetchCF' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_data_fetchCF', 'data_fetchCF' );
function data_fetchCF() {
    $id = $_POST['keyword'];
    echo get_the_title($id);
    echo do_shortcode('[wpforms id="'.$id.'"]');
    die();
} ?>
```

**Screenshots of the HTML output**

When embedded with a shortcode normally using the wordpress content editor (correct):
[image: Correct form action]

When loading the form by ID using the ajax function above:
[image: Replaced form action]

**How do I prevent replacing the form action with the ajax url so that the form is actually sent?**

Comment: You should open a ticket with the WPForms support team?  It's really hard to diagnose third party plugin issues because most of us aren't experts in any third party's plugin code.  That said, in your AJAX you are supplying the ADMIN AJAX url.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I don't think it has anything to do with the plugin but the way I use the ```action``` in the Ajax call. I am supplying the Ajax call as that's de default Wordpress call. Am I doing something incorrectly?